# Kendo charts display when values vary too much

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, kendo-ui

I have a kendo chart on my view that looks something like
[image]

You can see the x-axis label values overlap with each other because the series values too much. One solution is to increase the rendering space for the chart but in my case the UI does not allow increasing the space. How can I make this chart more bearable to the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- Combination of [steps](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#valueaxislabelsstep-numberdefault) and [skip](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#valueaxislabelsskip-numberdefault) to remove some of the valueAxis labels.
- [MajorUnit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#valueaxismajorunit-number) to set different interval between major divisions.

Comment: Additional approach: to better fit long chart label names try rotating them: `categoryAxis:{ labels: { rotation: -35}}`